Duplicate Rows in Grafana Table
I am using Grafana version grafana-10.3.3-1.x86_64 with Prometheus version 2.50.1 to monitor the OS metrics using this dashboard https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/11074
I found that the filesystem rows are duplicated in the Disk Space Used table although the duplicated row has the same values.
How to remove the duplicated rows and keep only one single row, please?


After investigating the issue, I found that's normal output because the instance is member of two jobs. So I added filter in the query using the $job varibale like the following:
node_filesystem_size_bytes{instance=~'$node',job='$job',fstype=~"ext.*|xfs",mountpoint !~".pod."}-0
node_filesystem_avail_bytes {instance=~'$node',job='$job',fstype=~"ext.*|xfs",mountpoint !~".pod."}-0
